# Update hash on scroll and other scroll events - performance issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am binding multiple events to a scroll event and I'm having performance issues when I try to update the hash using window.location.hash = "hash"; . The screen flickers and the page jumps randomly. **How can I optimize this code to increase performance and prevent the flickering and jumping on the page??**

I'm using the custom written jQuery scroll event below that updates various sections of the page when you've scrolled a certain distance (I've created variables for each of these sections that is a sum of all the divs in the section using .outerHeight). Everything is wrapped in $(window).on('load resize', function(){} to be sure the window has fully loaded before calculating heights.

The custom written jquery code is as follows:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){

        $(window).on('scroll', function(e){
            var scrollLength = $(window).scrollTop();
            var opacity = 0;
            if( scrollLength <= fadeStart ){
                opacity = 1;
            } 
            if (scrollLength <= fadeUntil ){
                opacity = 1- scrollLength/fadeUntil;
            }

            heroContent.css({
                'opacity' : opacity,
            });

            if (scrollLength < scroll1){
                $('.fixed-nav').removeClass('fixed'); 
            }
            if (scrollLength > scroll1 && scrollLength < scroll2){
                $('.fixed-nav').addClass('fixed');
                chapterNum.text('01');
                window.location.hash = "story1";
                $('.fixed-nav ul li').removeClass('active');
                $('.fixed-nav ul li:first-of-type').addClass('active');
            } 
            if (scrollLength > scroll2 && scrollLength < scroll3) {
                chapterNum.text('02');
                window.location.hash = "story2";
                $('.fixed-nav ul li').removeClass('active');
                $('.fixed-nav ul li:nth-of-type(2)').addClass('active');
            } 
            if (scrollLength > scroll3 && scrollLength < scroll4) {
                chapterNum.text('03');
                window.location.hash = "story3";
                $('.fixed-nav ul li').removeClass('active');
                $('.fixed-nav ul li:nth-of-type(3)').addClass('active');
            }
            if (scrollLength > scroll4 && scrollLength < scroll5) {
                chapterNum.text('04');
                window.location.hash = "story4";
                $('.fixed-nav ul li').removeClass('active');
                $('.fixed-nav ul li:nth-of-type(4)').addClass('active');
            }
            if (scrollLength > scroll5) {
                chapterNum.text('05');
                window.location.hash = "team";
                $('.fixed-nav ul li').removeClass('active');
                $('.fixed-nav ul li:nth-of-type(5)').addClass('active');
            }

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

A few pointers:

- You're setting a new event listener on every resize.
- Whenever you write `$("..")`, jQuery searches the DOM tree for the element you want to target. This is an 'expensive' action. Try to keep track of the elements you need to alter *outside* of the method that is executed on scroll.
- Use `else if` to prevent all `if` statements from being evaluated.

E.g.:

```
if (scrollLength < scroll1){ /* .. */ }
if (scrollLength > scroll1 && scrollLength < scroll2) { /* .. */ }
```

Can also be written as:

```
if (scrollLength < scroll1){ /* .. */ }
else if (scrollLength < scroll2) { /* .. */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is that the `$(window).on('scroll',...)` function is nested *inside* the `$(window).on('resize',...)` function. When the window is resized, additional bindings are applied to the window every time! You could use `.off()` but instead, I think it would be better to keep them separate:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
  $(window).scroll();
});

$(window).on('scroll',...);
```

As for updating the hash, use `replaceState` ([ref](https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/); this won't work in IE8/9)

```
window.history.replaceState({}, '', '#story3');
```